connecting karateFramework with dynamoDB
I would like to know, how I can connect my automation made on karate framework with DynamoDB. It's only for validate a row.
for example, I have a table named Users and I want to know if the user 'Nick" is registered.

This is very easy using the AWS Java SDK and Karate's Java interop. But it does require you to be able to write and compile one Java class - and most teams will be able to get this done. Keep in mind this is a one-time thing, and after the Java "helper" is in place, the whole team can focus on Karate *.feature files like normal.
A simple starter project is available that you can use as a reference: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/aws-dynamodb/README.md
For example:
package examples;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.GetItemRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.GetItemResponse;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DynamoDbUtils {

    final DynamoDbClient db;

    public DynamoDbUtils() {
        db = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create("myAwsProfile"))
                .region(Region.US_EAST_2)
                .build();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getItem(String keyValue) {
        Map<String, AttributeValue> keyToGet = new HashMap<>();
        keyToGet.put("myPrimaryKeyName", AttributeValue.builder().s(keyValue).build());
        // keyToGet.put("mySecondaryKeyName", AttributeValue.builder().s(keyValue).build());
        GetItemRequest get = GetItemRequest.builder().key(keyToGet).tableName("myTableName").build();
        GetItemResponse response = db.getItem(get);
        if (!response.hasItem()) {
            System.out.println("item not found by key: " + keyValue);
            return null;
        }
        Map<String, AttributeValue> row = response.item();
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("myFieldName", row.get("myFieldName").s());
        return result;
    }

}

Now using this in a Karate test is quite easy:
* def Utils = Java.type('examples.DynamoDbUtils')
* def db = new Utils()
* def result = db.getItem('myKeyValue')
* match result == { myFieldName: '#string' }

